# jq - flatten parent objects into children

Tags: json, parent-child, jq, reshape

I have the following source JSON which I need to reshape:

```
{
  "group": "A",
  "name": "abc",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "54209",
      "message": "foobar 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "76548",
      "message": "foobar 2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "group": "B",
  "name": "def",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "54593",
      "message": "foobar 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "20359",
      "message": "foobar 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get to the following output:

```
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "name": "abc",
    "id": "54209",
    "message": "foobar 1"
  },
  {
    "group": "A",
    "name": "abc",
    "id": "76548",
    "message": "foobar 2"
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "name": "def",
    "id": "54593",
    "message": "foobar 3"
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "name": "def",
    "id": "20359",
    "message": "foobar 4"
  }
]
```

I basically want a single array with all the child event arrays, but with their parent objects embedded into them.
I came very close with an example from this issue: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/646. But I need the keys as well, not just the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy all fields except **events** from the root to each *event*, and put resulting objects into an array.

```
jq -n '[ inputs | .events[] + del(.events) ]'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oXAS_oceHs)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Almost same logic as Oguz's answer, using `with_entries()` to remove events from root and adding the fields alone

```
jq -n '[ inputs | with_entries(select(.key != "events")) + (.events[]) ]'
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ec2DQdrLd2)</sup>